# Generating Single Port ROM on Spartan 6 using Xilinx ISE Design Suite

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, spartan

I'm having some trouble designing a single port rom onto a spartan 6 board. I use the provided core generator to create block memory and choose single port rom with 32 bit width and 256 depth with a coe file that just counts from 0 to 255. I drop the rom into my vhdl as a component and add the XilinxCoreLib as a library. When I try to generate the programming file I get the translate error:

```
logical block 'rom1' with type 'rom' could not be
resolved. A pin name misspelling can cause this, a missing edif or ngc file,
case mismatch between the block name and the edif or ngc file name, or the
misspelling of a type name. Symbol 'rom' is not supported in target
'spartan6'.
```

I'm currently using Xilinx ISE 13.1 if that helps. I feel like this should be really easy to do but I haven't been able to find how to do it.

Edit: Thanks everyone, was a combination of things. Wrong speed grade, and didn't add a copy of the ngc file to my working directory. I'll use arrays in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're adding a Xilinx generated core to your design in ISE, you need to add both the VHD file and the NGC file via "Add Source" via the Project menu.

Even easier, depending on how large your ROM needs to be and what data goes into it, would be to not even bother with a Xilinx core, but to use pure VHDL to declare a constant array and initialization values right in your VHDL file.  Here is an example:

```
type array_ROM is array (0 to NUMBER_OF_ROWS-1) of std_logic_vector (ROM_BITWIDTH-1 downto 0);

signal my_ROM : array_ROM
    :=
        (
            x"12345678",
            x"ABCDEF01",
            ...
            x"01010101"
        );
```

Now, you don't put the elipsis (...) in that initialization list, just put rows of constants with bit widths matching ROM_BITWIDTH.  The NUMBER_OF_ROWS is the number of address locations you need in the ROM.  In this example, ROM_BITWIDTH would have to be set to 32 as I've used 32-bit hexadecimal constants in the initialization list.  Being a signal, it's actually modifiable, so if you need it to be constant, just use "constant" instead of signal.

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to forget the vendor tools altogether and simply declare a constant array!

If this is in a package separate from the rest of the design, a few lines of printf's or a simple script can generate the VHDL boilerplate around the contents, which come from your assembler or whatever tool creates the actual data

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem is, as the message says, a misspelling. to get the correct component declaration/instantiation, select your rom.xco in the design-window of ISE. then select "view vhdl instantiation template" from process window. use the component declaration and instantiation described therein.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that can cause this problem, one is that you are using a blocck that was generated for another FPGA family and using it inside the Spartan6. the other is that you may have generated the ROM using an older version of the tool and the wrapper for the ROM has changed since then. 
You can either generate a anrray like Brian suggested and forgetting about the tool specific ROM type, or re-generate the IP under your curernt project settings and see how it goes.